# Как в openpyxl считать циклом данные из эксель, включая ячейки с формулами, как значения

Tags: python, openpyxl

У меня есть эксель файл, в котором я с помощью библиотеки openpyxl применяю формулы, потом мне необходимо данные,  в определённом диапазоне, записать в массив.
Я пробовала так:

```
array =[]
for row in xl_data.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=2, max_col=17, values_only=True) :
    array.append(row)
```

Где xl_data это лист эксель файла, с которого я считываю данные
Но ячейки которые я заполняла формулами, считываются текстом формулы (например '=SUM(B1:B4)' ), а не значением. **Подскажите можно ли считать формулы как значения, при этом с конкретного диапазона таблицы**

Я находила пример,

```
array=[]
for row in sheet.values:
    for value in row:
        array.append(value)
```

но мне он не подходит тк считывает значения со всего листа, а не с конкретного диапазона

Comment: openpyxl никогда не вычисляет формулу - [openpyxl never evaluates formula](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/simple_formulae.html)